# number of binary sets - combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binary

Just ran into this question:

let $f(n,m)$ be the number of binary strings where there are at most $n$ 1's and at most $m$ 0's.

the empty string also counts as a string.

show that $f(n,m)=\binom{n+m+2}{n+1}-1$.

thanks in advance,

Yaron.

Comment: Maybe one way would be by induction on $m$: If $m=0$, there are of course exactly $n+1$ such strings (namely a sequence of at least $0$ and at most $n$ 1s). With up to $m+1$ 0s, you can consider the 1s and insert the new 0 at any of the $n+1$ positions (you can ignore the 0s for the counting because the order of the different 0s certainly won't matter). Of course that way you'll miss out the empty string (because you explicitly added a 0), so add $1$ to the count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty direct proof. One would really hope for a combinatorial proof.

The obvious expression is $f(n,m)=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{i+j}{i}$.

But $$\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{i+j}{i}=\binom{i+m+1}{i+1}=\binom{i+m+1}{m}$$

So $$f(n,m)=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{i+m+1}{m} = -1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n+1}\binom{i+m}{m} = \binom{m+n+1+1}{m+1}-1$$

Which is the result you wanted.

This is using twice the identity $\sum_{k=0}^A \binom{B+k}{B} = \binom{B+A+1}{B+1}$, the first time with $A=m$ and $B=i$, the second time with $A=n+1$ and $B=i$.

Comment: You can find it on the Wikipedia page for binomial coefficients. I don't think it has a name, but the right side counts the number of ways of picking $B+1$ elements out of a set of $B+A+1$ elements. The value for $k$ counts those subsets where the maximum element is $B+k+1$. It's also absolutely trivial to prove by induction.